# Use Facebook cookies in script - getting logged

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I am trying to login into Facebook via cURL in PHP. At this moment, I want to get my cookies from the browser and use them as a cookie file in cURL.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Facebook detects and shuts down scrapers. Chances are your script will run into a captcha pretty quick.

Comment: I am trying to find out something, there is one corporation in Czech republic and they succesfully sent about 2 000 000 messages (spam) from 80 accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as FB is registering what you're doing, your account gets locked. There are several API frameworks out there to access FB and there's almost nothing left what can only be done by scraping there content.

Yes you can do it this way, but it's not the recommended way.

Comment: I want to log in with those cookies and then just simply send message to someone. I would use API, but you cannot send a message with it.

Comment: I downloaded all cookies from facebook and i have putted them into cookies.txt, in my script i used this : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");, but i am not logged.

Comment: I wrote "locked" in terms of "locked out" or "blocked", not logged. And of course you are as well logged.

Comment: Yes, i understand. I copied datr cookie into cookies.txt and i used it in cURL, but it still does not work.